# Liferay:Can portlet be triggered from other portlet

Tags: liferay-6

I have a requirement where information of various users(say A,B,C) is displayed and
a discussion is to be generated with current (logged in)user and the various users selected. 

For this i have developed two portlets-
1)Display portlet-show information of all users with a link to comment portlet.
2)Comment portlet-Users information is passed through the link.
 **Liferay.fire** and **Liferay.on** is used to pass information to comment portlet

Since both the portals are on same page. I want event to be triggered when a user is selected and then the corresponding comment portlet to be triggered.I want portlet to pop up once the link is clicked for a particular user. Please suggest,does **InterPortletCommunication Event** mechanism works here or some proper solution to do this.I am new to liferay please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using IPC. If it is same page then go for ajax based IPC.
Have a look into following link it may help you..

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/liferay-client-side-inter-portlet.html